# HashMap appears empty in certain situation

Tags: java, bukkit

I am developing a plugin for the minecraft server software Bukkit. There is a class that handles commands input by the users. I want to allow users to create and join existing teams. The teams are saved in a HashMap. The problem is that it works in one function just fine (/createteam), while the Map appears empty in /jointeam. If I call /createteam again, the entries are still there, so they're not getting deleted by accident. Here's my code:

```
package de.hoffmann.mcwar;

import java.util.HashMap;
...
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

public class MCWarCommandExecutor implements CommandExecutor {

private final MCWar plugin;

public Map<String, MCWarTeam> teamList = new HashMap<>();

public MCWarCommandExecutor(MCWar plugin) {
    this.plugin = plugin; // Store the plugin in situations where you need
                            // it.
}

@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    String playerName = sender.getName();

    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("launch")) {
        if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            sender.sendMessage("This command can only be run by a player.");
        } else {
            Player player = (Player) sender;
            if (args.length != 1) {
                return false;
            }

            int height = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            Location playerLocation = player.getLocation();

            Location newLocation = playerLocation;
            newLocation.setY(newLocation.getY() + height);

            String message = "Launching you up to height " + newLocation.getY();
            player.sendMessage(message);
            player.teleport(newLocation);

        }
        return true;
    }

    else if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("createTeam")) {
        sender.sendMessage("createTeam was called! Team list:");
        for (String key : teamList.keySet()) {
            sender.sendMessage(key);
        }
        if (args.length > 0 && args.length < 3) {
            String joinKey = "";
            if (args.length > 1)
                joinKey = args[1];

            String teamName = args[0];

            MCWarTeam newTeam = new MCWarTeam(teamName, joinKey);
            if (!teamList.containsKey(teamName)) {
                teamList.put(teamName, newTeam);
                sender.sendMessage("Created new team \"" + teamName + "\" with join key \"" + joinKey + "\" successfully! Teams:");

                sender.sendMessage("All teams:");
                for (String key : teamList.keySet()) {
                    sender.sendMessage(key);
                }

            } else
                sender.sendMessage("Team already exists!");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    else if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("joinTeam")) {
        sender.sendMessage("joinTeam was called! Team list:");
        for (String key : teamList.keySet()) {
            sender.sendMessage(key);
        }

        if (args.length > 0 && args.length < 3) {
            String joinKey = "";
            if (args.length > 1)
                joinKey = args[1];

            String teamName = args[0];

            if (teamList.containsKey(teamName)) {
                String teamKey = teamList.get(teamName).getJoinKey();
                if (joinKey == teamKey) {
                    teamList.get(teamName).addPlayer(playerName);
                    Bukkit.broadcastMessage("MCWar: " + playerName + " joined Team \"" + teamName + "\" successfully!");
                } else
                    sender.sendMessage("Join key incorrect!");
            } else {
                sender.sendMessage("Team doesn't exist! Teams:");
                for (String key : teamList.keySet()) {
                    sender.sendMessage(key);
                }

            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // else if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("leaveTeam")) {
    //
    // }
    //
    // else if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("ready")) {
    //
    // }
    //
    // else if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("notready")) {
    //
    // }
    //
    // else if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("surrender")) {
    //
    // }
    //
    // else if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("spectate")) {
    //
    // }
    //
    // else if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("setspawn")) {
    //
    // }
    //
    // else if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("kit")) {
    //
    // }
    //
    // else if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("showkits")) {
    //
    // }

    return false;
}
}
```

The formatting is a bit off so I put it here too: http://pastebin.com/zmdqFa3u

I tried changing places of the 2 functions in question but it doesn't help. I call a loop at the start of both functions, which should print all the elements of `teamList`. It only works in `createTeam` tho, none show up with the same loop in `joinTeam`. I'm afraid this problem might be a problem with how Bukkit stores data.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Hi Martin, first off, complexity of your method is too high I think.  You should try to lower it a bit.  At first glance, code seems ok. I`m not familiar with your context but my first thoughts would be that your class is instancied each time (which creates a new HashMap). Might wanna change it to a singleton and synchronize your teamList.

Comment: Maybe this is a concurrency issue? Not sure how bukkit will be handling these method invocations, but you may want to try using a ConcurrentHashMap

Comment: Thanks everybody for their answers. As you might be able to tell I'm not the best Java developer. @Apokai, if that's the case, wouldn't that mean I couldn't see the elements after calling `createteam` for the second time? So if I call it multiple times, it works and every added team shows up.

Comment: Martin, you are right but again, depends on the context.  Try this : print the hashcode of your HashMap, you will see if it`s the same reference (same object).  Guess not when you call jointTeam.

Comment: It would depend on the context of the thread that evaluates the object at runtime. Concurrency issues have a habit of being pretty random. I would try a thread safe collection.

Comment: I found a way to fix this now that I feel stupid for not coming up with it earlier. I save the `teamList` in another class (that is referenced in the constructor of the class of which the source code I provided above): `public MCWarCommandExecutor(MCWar plugin, HashMap<String,MCWarTeam> teamList) {
  this.plugin = plugin;
  this.teamList = teamList;
 }` is there anything wrong with that solution?

Comment: This is a question of design and it is hard to check without the big picture.  For instance, I see a lot of comments for future actions which mean that you will probably end up with other objects that you will need to pass as a reference (like teamList).  Your executor class will be a nightmare then.  For now, I think your new approach is safe in a single thread environment.  At least, use a ConcurrentHashMap has Mark said,you'll be ok.

Comment: Martin, have a look: http://pastebin.com/ptXDtUM5

Answer (score 2):

To explain this in Layman's terms, when registering your commands, you probably do it in this fashion:

```
@Override
public void onEnable()
{
    getCommand("foo").setExecutor(new Bar());
    getCommand("baz").setExecutor(new Bar());
}
```

If this is the case, a *separate instance* of these classes is made for each command, which means you also have separate Map instances, meaning their contents are not the same.

Make your Map `static` or change the way you register your commands:

```
Bar bar = new Bar();
getCommand("foo").setExecutor(bar);
getCommand("baz").setExecutor(bar);
```

Remember, this only applies if you register the commands as displayed in the code snippet at the top.